# Rgd: PHP exeed timeout when run exec or system call

Tags: php, wamp

My server is Window Server 2008, previously before reformat, I was able do exec call like

e.g a simple

```
<?php

System("C:\Windows\System32\calc.exe");

?>
```

or

```
<?php

exec("C:\Windows\System32\calc.exe");

?>
```

But when I enter this test.php with the code above at my browser be it Firefox or Chrome. It just keep buffering. like stuck or something until the php execution time out.

I have Administrator rights and I the only one using my window server 2008, its was until I reinstall the o.s due to hardware failure.

I using Wamp server , default setting with php safe mode off and curl enabled .

All i want try is a simple exec or system call to run the program. but seems unable execute , not sure if its permission issue or what. Anyone know how do I fix this issue.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You did not escape the backslash. Either quote the path with single quote:

```
<?php
exec('C:\Windows\System32\calc.exe');
?>
```

or escape the backslash.

Comment: "can't work" is not a valid issue description. Any further details?